# Using pip2 to install matplotlib yet returned such error

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I am Using pip2 to install matplotlib But getting this error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/pip2", line
> 5, in <module>
>     from pkg_resources import load_entry_point   File "/Users/TTH/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 3251, in <module>
>     @_call_aside   File "/Users/TTH/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 3235, in _call_aside
>     f(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/TTH/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 3264, in _initialize_master_working_set
>     working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()   File "/Users/TTH/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 585, in _build_master
>     return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)   File "/Users/TTH/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 598, in _build_from_requirements
>     dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())   File "/Users/TTH/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 786, in resolve
>     raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==19.0.3' distribution was
> not found and is required by the application ZENTs-MBP:~ TTH$ pip2
> list Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/pip2",
> line 5, in <module>
>     from pkg_resources import load_entry_point   File "/Users/TTH/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 3251, in <module>
>     @_call_aside   File "/Users/TTH/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 3235, in _call_aside
>     f(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/TTH/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 3264, in _initialize_master_working_set
>     working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()   File "/Users/TTH/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 585, in _build_master
>     return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)   File "/Users/TTH/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 598, in _build_from_requirements
>     dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())   File "/Users/TTH/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
> line 786, in resolve
>     raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==19.0.3' distribution was
> not found and is required by the application
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade `pip` first.

Run the following:

```
pip2 install --upgrade pip
```

and then proceed to install `matplotlib`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt reply. I’ve tried, but it throwback almost the same thing.